# How to alter array inside an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this JSON

```
{
    "Entries": [{
        "JobId": 7322,
        "DayOfTheWeek": "Wednesday",
        "Punchouts": ["2016-05-05T09:50:00", "2016-05-05T12:20:00"],
        "PunchIns": ["2016-05-05T10:10:00", "2016-05-05T12:40:00"]
    }, {
        "JobId": 7322,
        "DayOfTheWeek": "Thursday",
        "Punchouts": ["2016-05-05T09:50:00"],
        "PunchIns": ["2016-05-05T09:40:00"]
    }]
}
```

I would change it to

```
{
    "Entries": [{
        "JobId": 7322,
        "DayOfTheWeek": "Wednesday",
        "Punchout1": "2016-05-05T09:50:00",
        "Punchout2": "2016-05-05T12:20:00",
        "PunchIn1": "2016-05-05T10:10:00",
        "PunchIn2": "2016-05-05T12:40:00"
    }, {
        "JobId": 7322,
        "DayOfTheWeek": "Thursday",
        "Punchout1": "2016-05-05T09:50:00",
        "Punchout2": "",
        "PunchIn1": "2016-05-05T09:40:00"
        "PunchIn2": "",
    }]
}
```

I would like to condense the array. The array will have max length = 2. Even if the length is 0 / 1, the array should have empty string for *PunchOut1/PunchOut2* and *PunchIn1/PunchIn2*

Implemented it like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = data.Entries[i];
    if (entry["Punchouts"].length == 0) {
        entry["PunchOut1"] = "";
        entry["PunchOut2"] = "";
    }
    if (entry["Punchouts"].length == 1) {
        entry["PunchOut1"] = entry["Punchouts"][0];
        entry["PunchOut2"] = "";
    }
    if (entry["Punchouts"].length == 2) {
        console.log("in");
        entry["PunchOut1"] = entry["Punchouts"][0];
        entry["PunchOut2"] = entry["Punchouts"][1];
    }
    delete entry["Punchouts"];
    // do same for PunchIns.
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/rpgx28gy/

What would be a more optimized (preferably lodash) way?

Comment: When you ask for optimizations, are you looking for more concise code or for memory and or CPU optimization?

Comment: Your desired output isn't "condensed" - it's actually *more* characters.

Comment: @Alpha: read optimized as more readable, less code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better placed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (OP has working code but wants to streamline it).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Changed the title. I am using angularjs, All I need is to perform a siomple `ng-repeat` thats why I am reshaping the json

Comment: @nnnnnn: done. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/132412/1366

Comment: @naveen I've just provided an answer. If this is closed I'll move it over to Code Review too. Regardless, if you're using Angular for an ng-repeat, you can also an ng-repeat to iterate over punch ins and punch outs and you wouldn't have to modify the array at all.

Comment: @Alpha: this answer looks ok to me. I am changing the arrow function and trying it out in fiddle.

Comment: Point of education:  You have a JavaScript *object*.  JSON is a stringified format used for storage or transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var remappedEntries = _.map(data.Entries, e => ({
    JobId: e.JobId,
    DayOfTheWeek: e.DayOfTheWeek,
    PunchOut1: e.PunchOuts[0] || "",
    PunchOut2: e.PunchOuts[1] || "",
    PunchIn1: e.PunchIns[0] || "",
    PunchIn2: e.PunchIns[1] || "",
}));
```

This uses lodash's map, which iterates through every value and gives you an iteratee function that you can use to re-map that entry to another object. Note that you don't need to use lodash at all for this, you can use the `Array.prototype.map` function, assuming the browsers you aim for support it. There are also shims that you can use.

If instead of getting a copy you want to modify the exact same object, you can use `_.forEach`, or keep using map and discard the previous object. Really depends on your case.

I've also used arrow functions which make it simpler, from every "e" to the object that you want to return. Alternatively, this could be a named or an anonymous function that takes one parameter.

For each punchout, I'm taking advantage that you can check an array even if it doesn't have an object there. In that case, it'll return undefined. For those, we default them to empty string by using the conditional or, because undefined is considered "falsy" and so that expression will return the empty string. If it had a value, it'd use that one.

Comment: That `e.PunchOuts[0] || ""` mechanism is exactly what I would've suggested over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/132412/1366, but you've saved me the trouble. Nice work.